# Why do some metrics missing in cloudwatch metrics view?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cloudwatch

I am using cloudwatch metric view to view dyanmodb metrics. When I search `ReadThrottleEvents`, only a few tables or index shown in the list. I wonder why the metrics are not visible for all tables? Is there any configuration I need to configure in order to view them?

Below is a screenshot of searching this metrics and I expect every table index should be shown in the list. But I only got 2 results.

[image]

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear why that happens?

Comment: In our case, custom metrics only showed up in the list after specifying a default value  for the metric filter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If there is [no data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/viewing_metrics_with_cloudwatch.html), they don't show:

> **Metrics that have not had any new data points in the past two weeks do not appear in the console**. They also do not appear when you type their metric name or dimension names in the search box in the All metrics tab in the console, and they are not returned in the results of a list-metrics command. The best way to retrieve these metrics is with the get-metric-data or get-metric-statistics commands in the AWS CLI.

Comment: where do you see this in aws doc? I can see there are some metrics who don't have any value in the metrics value.

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao I linked the docs in the answer.